# How do I create a background with a small heart patter?

Tags: html, css

something similar to this image but pink [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sG2ut.jpg)

Comment: What have you tried so far? where are you stuck? shouldnt be to hard with a normal backgroudn image and using `background-repeat`...

Comment: I only tried to set the image I found on google as the background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find a small background image of the heart you would like to use and use the `background-repeat` CSS property to have it repeat across the x and y axes.

Something similar to this should work:

```
body {
   background-image: url("heart-image.png");
   background-repeat: repeat;
}
```